# Separating Node.js server and client

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I am writing a web app with a Server and a Client.

- The **server** functions as an API, and uses [express](http://expressjs.com/) framework.
- The **client** is just a `node-static` app that serves static javascript/html files.

I want to be able to deploy them separately, independently of each other - or both at the same time.

Here is how I envision the directory structure:

```
 /my-app
     app.js
     /server
         server.js
     /client
         client.js
```

I would like to be able to run this in 3 different ways:

1. Run just the server (API) on some port (say 3000):

   ```
   my-app/server> node server.js
   ...Server listening on localhost:3000/api
   ```
2. Run just the client (i.e. serve static files from /client directory):

   ```
   my-app/client> node client.js
   ...Server listening on localhost:4000/client
   ```
3. Run both the server and the client, on the same port (by single node.js instance):

   ```
   my-app> node app.js
   ...Server listening on localhost:5000
   ```

Is this possibe in node and what is the proper way to configure it?

I started as follows:

```
/////////////
// server.js
/////////////
// Run the server if this file is run as script
if(module.parent){
   app.listen("3000/client")  
}

/////////////
// client.js
/////////////
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new(static.Server)('.');
var app = require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
  request.addListener('end', function () {
    file.serve(request, response);
  });
});
if(module.parent){
   app.listen("4000/client");
}

/////////////
// app.js
/////////////
server = require("server/server.js")
server.app.listen("5000/api")

client = require("client/client.js")
client.app.listen("5000/client")  <--- ?????
```

I am not sure how to hook up both **client** and **server** inside my **app.js** so that they are both served from the same port/process/thread etc...

*NOTE: Excuse the code, it is not tested and probably incorrect. I am new to node.js*

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: In my answer I'm assuming that by "client" you refer to the html/css/js/... that should be server statically to the browser. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes! You are understanding me exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can instantiate a [`connect`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) (the guts of `express`) server instance when starting both the server and the client from the same script and have it route the requests to `node-static` when the url starts with `public` and to `connect` otherwise.

Something like

```
var connect = require('connect');
server = connect.createServer();
server.use('/public', client.handler_function);
server.use(server.express_handler_function);
```

should do. You'll need to expose the `function(request, response)` in `client.js` so that it can be referenced through `client.handler_function` and do the same for the express app (refer to the documentation).

For example, esposing the function in `client.js` would involve something like:

```
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new(static.Server)('.');
var handler = function (request, response) {
  request.addListener('end', function () {
    file.serve(request, response);
  });
};
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
if(module.parent){
   app.listen(4000);
   console.log("Server (static) listening on 4000")
}
module.exports = { handler_function: handler };
```

So that you can get to `handler` by doing:

```
var client = require('client'); // this returns the object you've set to `module.exports` in `client.js`
[...]
server.use('/public', client.handler_function);
```

### Other approaches

What I've detailed above seems to be the closest to what you want (based on the clarification in your last edit). There are other options, though:

- keep static and express-generated urls based at the site root, such as `example.com/a_statically_served_script.js` and `example.com/api_endpoint`; serving a static file is attempted first, if one cannot be found you'll dispatch the request to the express-based app
- use the `app.js` script to start both servers on different ports (or unix domain sockets) and use [node-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) (or something similar, or even nginx/apache as a reverse proxy) in front of them

### Same root

For the first approach you need to add an error handler to `file.serve` such as

```
file.serve(request, response, function(e, res) {
    if (e && (e.status == 404)) {
        // if the file wasn't found
        if (next) {
            next(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

`next` should be a variable in the `client.js` script that is not set when the script is run directly but it is when the script is required (have a look at the documentation for how modules and exports in node work) - when set, `next` refers to a function that takes `(req, res)` and feeds them to express (have a look at the express docs on how to do this).

### Remarks

Keep in mind this isn't an exhaustive answer: it's just a bunch of pointers on what documentation to look up and what techniques you could use to solve the problems.

Something worth remembering is that more often than not in node a request handler is represented and implemented by a `function(request, response)`. This idiom is extended in `connect`/`express` to `funciton(request, response, next)`: here `next` represents the next avaliable handler (of the form `function(request, response)`) in the chain of handlers mounted to the server through `server.use(handler)`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I completely forgot to mention that I didn't expect both client and server to be served at the same url.  Sorry that would be silly of course! I meant something like `localhost:5000/server` and `localhost:5000/client` ... Basically as you indicated (I've update the question to reflect the urls that would serve the content in each case, thanks!)

Comment: Thanks - great answer. I'm still a bit unclear as to what you mean by "expose the `function(request, response)`" - perhaps you could point me to the related section in the docs somewhere or let me know what to search for? Cheers!

Comment: I'm happy this helps! I've extended the answer with an example. Let me know if it's not clear. Search for 'creating a module in nodejs' for more info on how modules work. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

I had similar requirements to the OP, but didn't need to execute subsections separately... I only wanted separate folders as I don't like nesting client code within the server's code folder. Technically it's impossible to avoid doing so, so instead I created a level of abstraction in the filesystem to ease my troubled soul. Here is the root of my project:

```
-client
-server
-node_modules
-app.js
```

`client` contains everything that `public` usually would (all client-side files to be served), i.e. at least `index.html`.

`server` may or may not be a Node module (in my case it didn't have to be). Herein lies your app-specific server code. You can re-`require` the same files as in your underlying `app.js`, as it won't make any difference and will work just fine.

`node_modules` is obviously required by Node, and is best left at the root of the project, since that way any `require`s in `server` can search upward through the project folder hierarchy to [find this common repository of modules at the root](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules).

`app.js` simply contains the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
app = express();
require('./server/server.js');

app.use(express.directory(path.join(__dirname, '/'))); //optional, directory browsing
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
app.use(express.errorHandler());

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

...So as you can see, there is minimal code in the root script. All really important, application-specific

Note that the variable `app` is *not* declared using `var`. By avoiding `var`, we make it global and allows it to be accessed within `server.js` without further ado.

So you would do `node app` to get this running, if that wasn't already clear.

Comment: How did you configure the `package.json` file for this dir/file structure?

Comment: @InfZero Wish I could help but 4 years was a long time ago.

Answer (score 4):

How about using reverse proxy like `Nginx`?

You can easily bind two node apps in one port, and there's many other advantages.

http://wiki.nginx.org/Main

Comment: Thanks, but I am running in Heroku. And I want to keep the number of node apps to a minimum - just 1.